# React Native button is not changing width

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I'm a 13-year-old react-native beginner. I would like to know why my buttons width isn't changing. I checked several websites but I couldn't;t find any answers. Please change my code and show what I did wrong.

Thank you.

```
import React from "react";
import {
  ImageBackground,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
  Button,
  Alert,
} from "react-native";

const image = {
  uri:
    "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1498036882173-b41c28a8ba34?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&w=1000&q=80",
};

const ReactApp = () => (
  <View style={styles.container}>
    <ImageBackground source={image} style={styles.image}>
      <Text style={styles.text}>React native</Text>
      <Button
        title="Button"
        color="#042e6e"
        onPress={() => Alert.alert("Button pressed")}
      />
    </ImageBackground>
  </View>
);

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    flexDirection: "column",
  },
  image: {
    flex: 1,
    resizeMode: "cover",
    justifyContent: "center",
  },
  text: {
    color: "white",
    fontSize: 30,
    fontWeight: "bold",
    alignSelf: "center",
  },
});
export default ReactApp;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cant put styles directly to a button
you have to wrap it in a view and set the width of the view

```
<View style={{width:100}}>
     <Button
        title="Button"
        color="#042e6e"
        onPress={() => Alert.alert("Button pressed")}
      />
</View>
```